# SQLite average function

Tags: php, sqlite, average

I'm currently  using the following code to use PHP to grab data from an SQLite database. This extracts all data from column1 where the date is greater than a date I specify. The output goes into $output, where I can then stick the data in a table.

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->open('database_name.sdb');
  }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
   echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
  echo "Opened database successfully<br /><br />";
}

$sql =<<<EOF
  SELECT * FROM "archive" WHERE "dateTime" > $specified_time;
EOF;
$ret = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
$output = $row['column1'];
}
```

I now want to get the average of values in 'column 2' (where the date is greater than a certain date) and put it into a PHP variable. This is the code I'm using but it's returning a blank. I've  tried a  few other things too, but to no avail.

```
$sql =<<<EOF
SELECT AVG("column2") FROM "archive" WHERE "dateTime" > $specifiedtime;
EOF;
$ret = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
$output = $row['AVG("column2")'];
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alias for your calculated column

```
SELECT AVG(column2) as avg_col2 FROM ...
```

Then you can name that column in PHP

```
$output = $row["avg_col2"];
```